# Android defstyle parameter

Tags: android

All the classes in Android that can be built using XML have constructors of the form:

```
Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle
```

What is the `defstyle` parameter?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All Views supply this constructor, so every subclass can use its own base style when inflating.

For the param, I'd like to quote the docs for the [View-Class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html):

> *defStyle* The default style to apply
>   to this view. If 0, no style will be
>   applied (beyond what is included in
>   the theme). This may either be an
>   attribute resource, whose value will
>   be retrieved from the current theme,
>   or an explicit style resource.

Comment: But what do you do with it? For example when you design a custom view. How to load a style. Ot is it enought to pass it one to `super`?

Answer (score 6):

This seems to be broken for custom views which programmatically supply their default style through the constructor, see the google code [issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12683).

Comment: is there any fix for this issue other than inflating xml layout?

Answer (score 3):

Quote from [alanv, project member](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12683#c15), "The documentation is incorrect. The third constructor must be an attribute, e.g. R.attr.*"