# I want to extend View from a Activity class

Tags: android, extend

Currently I have a class called MapActivity that extends AppCompatActivity, and I need this because I have a acitivity_map.xml, but the thing is, I want to extend View, so that I can draw things on this activity.

How can I achive this ?

Comment: Don't draw on the activity itself. Draw on one of its elements instead

Comment: Agreed. Create a separate `View` class that is your drawing surface, and add it to your activity.

Comment: How do I add that to my activity ? Currently I have a seperate View Class But I dont see how I can add it to my activity ?

Comment: Using `setContentView(View view)`;

Comment: This way, I cant see my buttons.. it like takes over the whole activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently i had the same question. Here is what i got:
Create your own view:

```
public class CustomView extends View
```

Override the onDraw() method like this:

```
 @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.save();
        //draw something
        canvas.restore();
 }
```

In your Activity in onCreate:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_name);
    com.XXX.XXX.CustomView cV = (com.XXX.XXX.CustomView) findViewById(R.id.customView);
```

And in the xml:

```
<com.XXX.XXX.CustomView
        android:id="@+id/customView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: This answer could be useful, if you're looking for this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739661/error-inflating-when-extending-a-class