# Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-support-design

I am trying to get my layout working that would be implementing the support design library features. However when I try running the project I am getting following exception when my layout is being loaded.

> Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error
>   inflating class android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
  <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="@color/main_grey">
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
      <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
          android:layout_height="192dp"
          android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
          >
          <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:minHeight="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/actionbar_background">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/psonar_logo"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
                android:visibility="gone" />
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/toolbarTitles"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone">
              <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/toolbarTitle"
                  android:ellipsize="end"
                  android:maxLines="1"
                  android:textSize="18dp"
                  android:textColor="@color/white"
                  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
              <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/toolbarSubtitle"
                  android:ellipsize="end"
                  android:maxLines="1"
                  android:textColor="@color/white"
                  android:gravity="center_vertical"
                  android:visibility="gone"
                  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_below="@+id/toolbarTitle" />
            </RelativeLayout>
          </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
      </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
      <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
          android:id="@+id/scroll"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:clipToPadding="false"
          app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
        <FrameLayout
          android:minWidth="25px"
          android:minHeight="25px"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="175dp"
          android:id="@+id/carouselFrameLayout" />
      </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
      android:layout_above="@id/miniPlayerHolder"
      android:background="@color/main_grey"
      android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
      android:orientation="vertical">
      <TabHost
          android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
          <TabWidget
              android:id="@android:id/tabs"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="45dp"
              android:tabStripEnabled="false"
              android:layout_weight="0"
              android:showDividers="none" />
          <FrameLayout
              android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="0dp"
              android:layout_weight="0" />
          <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
              android:id="@+id/pager"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="0dp"
              android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
      </TabHost>
    </LinearLayout>
    <include
      layout="@layout/mini_player_holder" />
  </RelativeLayout>
  <!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
         this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
         languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
         The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
         the container. A solid background is used for contrast
         with the content view. -->
  <include
      layout="@layout/home_drawer_menu" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I tried building simple test project that was implementing the **CollapsingToolbarLayout** and it worked without any issues but as soon as I try putting it into my project it stops working.

I checked nuget packages and they seem to be installed fine. Our theme is inheriting from: **Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar**.

Stacktrace:

> {Android.Views.InflateException: Exception of type
>   'Android.Views.InflateException' was thrown. at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
>   [0x0000b] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/2185/53fce373/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.ExceptionServices/ExceptionDispatchInfo.cs:61
>   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallNonvirtualVoidMethod
>   (intptr,intptr,intptr,Android.Runtime.JValue*) [0x00084] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/2185/53fce373/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:1029
>   at Android.App.Activity.SetContentView (int) [0x00070] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/2185/53fce373/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-23/src/generated/Android.App.Activity.cs:5872
>   at Psonar.Apps.Droid.PayPerPlay.HomeActivity.OnCreate
>   (Android.OS.Bundle) [0x00009] in
>   E:\Dev\psonar\Source\Psonar.Apps\Psonar.Apps.Droid\Psonar.Apps.Droid.PayPerPlay\UI\HomeActivity.cs:66
>   at
>   Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentActivity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_
>   (intptr,intptr,intptr)  at (wrapper
>   dynamic-method) object.14ce2242-aa35-41bb-a113-286527a98d77
>   (intptr,intptr,intptr)
>
> --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error
>   inflating class android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)  at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:255)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
>     at md5cdb4fd1f07f997be815955fad4cc2feb.HomeActivity.n_onCreate(Native
>   Method)   at
>   md5cdb4fd1f07f997be815955fad4cc2feb.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:38)
>     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)   ...
>   25 more Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field
>   TextAppearance_android_shadowColor of type I in class
>   Landroid/support/design/R$styleable; or its superclasses (declaration
>   of 'android.support.design.R$styleable' appears in
>   /data/app/com.psonar.android-1/base.apk)  at
>   android.support.design.widget.CollapsingTextHelper.setExpandedTextAppearance(CollapsingTextHelper.java:230)
>     at
>   android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout.(CollapsingToolbarLayout.java:185)
>     at
>   android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout.(CollapsingToolbarLayout.java:126)
>     ... 28 more }

Comment: Are you sure that's the layout that's causing the problem?

Comment: @MikeM. I haven't done any changes anywhere else so I would suspect that it would be the layout.

Comment: Well, the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` is not on `Binary XML file line #2` in that file. Inspect your stacktrace, and see what class is trying to inflate the problematic layout.

Comment: @MikeM. added stacktrace

Comment: If that's the layout you're setting as the content View in `HomeActivity`, I guess that must be it. Maybe Xamarin compiles its resource files differently.

Comment: @MikeM. yep, that is correct, it is the layout I am setting in HomeActivity.

Comment: What caught my eye is "java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field TextAppearance_android_shadowColor of type"

Comment: I'm not sure. Googling the error `NoSuchFieldError: No static field` gives results with a bunch of different situations. Are you using any libraries in your project?

Comment: did you notice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739661/android-error-inflating-class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wish the solution was something else but simple re-install of Support Design Library packages did the trick. I had to do it through Xamarin Studio though as Visual Studio was misbehaving in this case.